# Best Linux os for Dell Vostro A860

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I am using Vostro A860 with Windows XP now. I want to migrate to linux os. Please consider the below before suggesting.

1) T2390 Processor
2) 2GB Ram
3) I want to use if for webdevelopment (PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with mitsosc on Ubuntu because Dell chose ubuntu as their official goto linux flavor and they also ship with Ubuntu.

For development purposes like you mentioned PHP, you might want to keep your environment as similar to your production/staging server. For e.g. if you use CentOS on the server to host PHP then Fedora maybe a better choice as CentOS is not well suited for desktops/laptops.

As for system support I beleive fedora may do just as well but ofcourse Ubuntu "should" have no problems at all.

If you dont really care about production/deployment on the server side then its great just go for ubuntu. I have been a happy camper for 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It will cover all your needs and Performance should be decent too.
http://www.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) is a great choice. The community is helpfull for any newbie and its a great intro into linux! It also runs fine on older computers.